# Preventing Undefined Macro

Tags: c++, c, macros, c-preprocessor

In C and C++, when using a macro like so:

```
#if ( 1 == __MY_MACRO__ )
// Some code
#endif
```

The compiler will not catch if **MY_MACRO** is not defined and will consider it 0. This could cause a lot of hidden bugs when the design of the code is intended such that the macro must be defined (non-zero).

Is there away to get to compiler to report this, even if the compiler natively doesn't look for such thing?

Comment: "The compiler will not catch if MY_MACRO is not defined and will consider it 0" this is not true. If __MY_MACRO__ is undefined, the compiler will report an error.

Comment: It will not report error, based on several compilers I've tested on, including Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: @nos Yes I was wrong now I see it is within `#if`. The C++ standard says that all undefined identifiers there are replaecd with `0`.

Comment: it is a bit late :-), but I solved the same problem using function like macro. See the implementation in my answer. If seems prettiest of all suggested workarounds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#ifndef __MY_MACRO__
  #error "MY_MACRO NOT DEFINED"
#endif
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `#if defined(__MY_MACRO__)` to test if the macro value is defined.

Comment: Or `#ifdef` or `#ifndef` depending on whether you want to catch it being defined or not defined.

Comment: +1, but it's not a function. :) In other words, `#if defined __MY__MACRO` works just as well.

Comment: @unwind - quite true, I just like things to look like functions for some reason! Thanks for the upvote.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `#ifdef` or `ifndef` to check if a macro is defined of not.

Example :

```
#ifndef MY_MACRO
# error "MY_MACRO is not defined"
#endif
```

More informations can be found here : https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Ifdef.html

Comment: I'm not trying to define the macro if it isn't.  I want to make sure the check is valid, and the macro must be pre-defined.

Answer (score 0):

I have to resort to

```
#if !defined( __MY_MACRO__ )
MACRO_NOT_DEFINED;  //to cause compiler error
#endif
#if ( 1 == __MY_MACRO__ )
//code
#endif
```

Which looks rather ugly.

Comment: Yes, but some compiler does not recognize #error, sadly.  Thanks.

Comment: "Yes, but some compiler does not recognize `#erro`" - and what do they do about it?  Print an error right?  So, might as well use `#error` anyway - regardless of exactly what message gets printed it helps people looking at the error line understand what you intended.  Separately, you can combine `#endif` and the following `#if (1 == ...` into `#elif (1 == ...` and save a line.  And you shouldn't be using double underscores - that's reserved for the implementation.

Comment: The standard (all versions) requires that `#error` stop compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Someone I know came up with a clever 1 liner

```
#if ( (1/defined(_MY_MACRO__) && 1 == _MY_MACRO__ ) )
//code
#endif
```

If _MY_MACRO__ is not defined, it will cause divide by zero error.

Answer (score 0):

If the macro is used as compile switch try this way.
in a configuration file:

```
#define FEATURE_1_ENABLED() (1)
#define FEATURE_2_ENABLED() (0)
```

in place you checking the value:

```
#if FEATURE_1_ENABLED()
// whatever
#endif
```

in contrast to your example this does show error when macro is not visible by mistake (at least in my ide)